# Bash cat -> separate strings into new line

Tags: linux, bash

When I use `cat file_name.txt` I get the logs in one line. How to separate each string to new line?

```
"Rest API SRV01""Rest API SRV02""Rest API SRV01"
```

Expected output:

```
"Rest API SRV01"
"Rest API SRV02"
"Rest API SRV01"
```

Comment: It'd be worth knowing the file's actual format; if it has NULs between the strings, f/e, that allows an answer that's both simpler and more reliable than your currently selected one. Use `cat -A file_name.txt` on a GNU system, or `xxd file_name.txt` more portably to get a dump that will show any hidden/nonprintable characters between your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to replace each `""` with `"\n`:

```
sed 's/\"\"/\"\n\"/g' <<< '"Rest API SRV01""Rest API SRV02""Rest API SRV01"'
```

```
"Rest API SRV01"
"Rest API SRV02"
"Rest API SRV01"
```

Comment: Thx, I am doing sth like that done > test.txt && cat test.txt. How to use sed with those commands ( | or &&)?

Comment: Not sure what your asking. Please add the command you're using (or trying to fix) to your question.

Comment: done > test.txt && sed 's/\"\"/\"\n\"/g' test.txt ---> it works properly :)

Comment: @sk306 Why have a `test.txt` at all? `done | sed ...`; even if you want the file, `done | tee test.txt | sed ...` will let `sed` process content as the while loop prints it instead of needing to wait for the loop to finish before sed can start at all.